# How to compile an Angular template and insert it in DOM with appendChild?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-compile

I'm trying to insert a new  into page html. This div should get it's content from an Angular template.

I've tried this and it doesn't work.

```
var tpl = $compile( '"<div ng-include="template.tpl.html"></div>"' )( scope );
document.body.appendChild(tpl);
```

tpl returns null.

Comment: Try injecting $document, and doing $document.body.appendChild(tpl). It might be outside of the angular scope, so that would fix it, or a $scope.$apply().

Answer (score 2):

Don't be tempted to do that. I know when dealing with jQuery and coming to Angular we feel the urge to try to use strings for everything, and appendTo, prepend, replaceWith.

Directives are your best bet, and you don't need to get your hands jQuery-dirty.

```js
app.directive('includeIt', function(){
  return { 
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {template:'=includeIt'},
    template: '<div ng-include="template"></div>'
  };
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function(){
   this.templates = ['template1.tpl.html','template2.tpl.html'];
});
```

then you use the directive in your HTML

```html
<div ng-controller="Ctrl as ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="template in ctrl.templates" include-it="template"></div>
</div>
```

This way you can include automatically all your "templates" automatically, that appends to the DOM without you having to touch jQuery. See it in action here http://plnkr.co/edit/WFEcB1QJlD9D98rC57J9?p=preview